# Question has been edited and I don't understand why

Tags: support

My question has been edited to put some terms in grey highlighting and I don't understand why.

what does the grey highlighting mean?

[How to see items deleted by other users?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180213/how-to-see-items-deleted-by-other-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many reason for editing a post. But if i consider your post then you have used a term **ootb** which is not a original word, its an abbreviation of **Out of The Box**. As we all are aware that abbreviations are always written in capital letters.

Also if you use some of the word that describe some product feature like you used "**site collection Recycle Bin**" while we all know that this term is written in SharePoint site as "**Site Collection Recycle Bin**".

Make one thing sure that if your post has been edited it doesn't mean that someone is trying to make you feel that you have done mistake in post, its just they want to maintain the decorum of the SE so that we can have the best quality of posts.

Comment: The point is that many times such minor edits really only fix capitalization or turn some method name in a code snippet... all while ignoring any bigger  other problem the post may have (grammar, off-topic-question in the first place and so on). Add on top of this that such edits are most of the time proposed by <2k rep users and you may soon understand why edits that only seem to want to grab the +2 rep prize with the minimal effort aren't exactly well regarded.

Comment: Lucky we are a low traffic site, so the review queues never have many items in the first place, but this doesn't mean we should completely disregard the network etiquette of avoiding minor edits if you are a <2k user.

Comment: (PS: I hope it is clear this isn't directed at you. It is just a note I wanted to make since I'm seeing an increase in minor edits recently)

Comment: Totally agree with you @SPArchaeologist

Answer (score 4):

Primary reason for editing questions is applying proper formatting to question. So it becomes more readable. It gives proper understanding what is question about and what are important things to look after.

`Grey Highlighted` means its a code block with preformatting applied. If you post some piece of code it will loose all indents, spacing, formatting. But if you apply it the `Grey Highlighted` formatting it will look pretty like the code in visual studio/ or some editor (but not in readonly mode).

Comment: Yes I have seen that before, but there is no code in my question?

Comment: probably you can see history what was edited

Answer (score 2):

I'm a regular user and I really don't think that edit was necessary. Gray highlights are used for either code, or columns, or SharePoint-specific code terms. I wouldn't have approved this edit.

Comment: Agree, some folks are just editing posts which are perfectly fine in the first place. Maybe points? not trying to stir a hornet's nest here :)

Comment: Same here, that edit is not really a valid edit. Marking up keywords with `code snippets` does not do anything for the post